# Call Gridview Rowdatabound Event from jQuery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing Asp web application using c#, in which I am having Gridview and inside gridview there is Asp linkbutton.

On click of linkbutton I am calling jQuery model popUp which is having ok cancel button inside model popup. I want to call GridView RowDataBound event after clicking OK button of jQuery model pop up.

I write the code of postback on Ok button (inside jQuery function) which is as follows:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdOrder_ctl02_btnSpIns', '')
```

Click and page is post back but not calling the GridView RowDataBound.

How can I call that event?  Because grid bind on only that event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
__doPostBack('_ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdOrder$_ctl02$btnSpIns','')
```

Comment: @user1432131 just see in your page's rendered html. You will find the correct ID to use for doing the postback: Eg: `<a  id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdOrder_ctl02_btnSpIns" href="javascript:__doPostBack('SEE WHAT IS PRESENT HERE','')"/>`

Comment: Thanks again ..I written in my question that page is post back properly...But i want to call gridview RowDataBound event on click of OK Button of jquery Model Pop Up.